# How to make a jar file run at start up

Tags: java, jar

I have a game that has a side application that acts as an updater. The updater can check for updates hourly, daily or weekly. I want this updater to be ran at startup so that it can check for updates. How do i make my executable jar file run at startup on a windows xp and windows 7?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**1.** goto Start -> Run and then write "REGEDIT"

goto HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/MICROSOFT/Windows/Current Version/Run

Add a String on the right side, and set the Path for your JAR file.

**2.** Or you can add your JAR file into START/ALL PROGRAMS/Autostart

Comment: I want to be able to do it programatically

Comment: @JohnDetter You can modify the registry programatically.

Comment: @John http://stackoverflow.com/questions/62289/read-write-to-windows-registry-using-java StackOverflow does have a search bar. Use it.